# Error in cramerV : object 'Phi' not found (library rcompanion, R)

Tags: r

I have installed rcompanion library with version 0.99.44 DescTools.
When I try to run the function `cramerV` on my table, I get an error: `Error in cramerV(variableName) : object 'Phi' not found`.
Any ideas what is going on? The library has been loaded using `library(rcompanion)` before calling the function.

Answer (score 2):

OK the solution is:

The argument I was passing inside the `cramerV()` function was `class tibble`. Turns out it only accepts matrix (precisely: "Either a two-way table or a two-way matrix. Can also be a vector of observations for one dimension of a two-way table." from documentation https://rdrr.io/cran/rcompanion/man/cramerV.html)

Therefore solved by converting variable to a matrix using `as.matrix(variableName)`